# Enterprise architect: Generate a list of Ids and not full instances in xsd

Tags: xsd, enterprise-architect

I want to model a container that has a list of references by id in enterprise architect.

[image]

A xsd is generated from that model.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Container" type="Container"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Container">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Element" type="Element" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Element" type="Element"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Element">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is it possible to find settings so such  that a list of Id is generated?

(Not a list of full instances like it is now)

Here are the settings of the aggregation:

[image]

The goal is to have a list of ID in the container generated from the association and have the possibility to generate java code from the xsd that has a list of element, not ID.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Container" type="Container"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Container">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ElementRef" type="xs:IDREF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Element" type="Element"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Element">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Identifier" type="xs:ID" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

So, the XSD shall have a list of `IDREF`, so that the java code generated from that shall have either a list of Identifiers or even better a list of `Element`.

Edit: added example of target xsd.

Comment: I think I want to do something very similar to you, but I'm not totally clear what you are looking for. Can you supply an edited XSD that represents what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: @Screwtape Please have a look at the updated question

Comment: Did you found a solution?